# T-SQL query to match next row as a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table and I need to match row 1 to row 2, row 3 to row 4 and so on..

```
Userid, CheckTime
------------------------------    
90119, 2014-05-08 11:03:09.000
90119, 2014-05-08 11:47:05.000
90119, 2014-05-12 22:10:39.000
90119, 2014-05-12 22:41:35.000
90119, 2014-05-13 00:58:26.000
90119, 2014-05-13 01:03:25.000
90119 | 2014-05-13 22:11:49.000
90119 | 2014-05-13 22:42:07.000
```

I need to do a query that will give the following results:

```
Userid, CheckTimeA,             ChecktimeB
---------------------------------------------    
90119, 2014-05-08 11:03:09.000, 2014-05-08 11:47:05.000
90119, 2014-05-12 22:10:39.000, 2014-05-12 22:41:35.000
90119, 2014-05-13 00:58:26.000, 2014-05-13 01:03:25.000
90119, 2014-05-13 22:11:49.000, 2014-05-13 22:42:07.000
```

Comment: It would be nice were you to include the name of the table, and were you to format the example data so that it might be visually understood more readily. Furthermore, some context and background – tho not too much! – would serve to convince the potential answerers of your question that you haven't fell prey to [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). It's also nice, in general, to include the version(s) of the relevant software, that those who choose to help you might verify the correctness of their proposals.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Userid, CheckTime, Ordinal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Userid ORDER BY CheckTime )
INTO #times
FROM insert_your_table_name_here;

SELECT t_odds.Userid, CheckTimeA = t_odds.CheckTime, CheckTimeB = t_evens.CheckTime
FROM    #times t_odds
        JOIN #times t_evens
            ON  t_odds.Userid = t_evens.Userid
                AND t_odds.Ordinal + 1 = t_evens.Ordinal
WHERE t_odds.Ordinal % 2 = 1;

DROP TABLE #times;
```

Comment: The `WHERE` condition on t_evens doesn't seems to be needed, it's implicit in the `JOIN` given the conditions on t_odds

Answer (score 0):

Relying that corresponding records in your actual table are stored as sequential pairs (1-2, 3-4, 5-6, etc) I would propose you to use [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
;WITH 
startTime as (
  SELECT Userid, CheckTime, ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Userid ORDER BY CheckTime ) 
     from dbo.UserCheckLog 
   where ID % 2 = 1 ) 
,
endTime as (
  SELECT Userid, CheckTime, ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Userid ORDER BY CheckTime ) 
     from dbo.UserCheckLog 
  where ID % 2 = 0) 
select startTime.UserID, startTime.CheckTime as CheckTimeA, endTime.CheckTime as CheckTimeB
   from startTime
left join endTime on startTime.ID = endTime.ID + 1
```

(just put your actual table name instead 'dbo.UserCheckLog').